# *ngFor loop with async pipe?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Reading through [this article](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/06/14/routing-in-angular-2-revisited.html) and it has an ngFor loop like this:

```
*ngFor="let contact of contacts | async"
```

How does the `async` pipe work in this context?

Comment: https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe.  In other words, it tells the component to update when a new value is emitted (as opposed to an entire collection upfront) via a RxJS subscription.  It also automatically unsubscribes the component from the observable when the component is destroyed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The async pipe gives the latest value from an observable. In this case (as in other cases) it will refresh the data involved when a new value comes down the observable. So if the screen renders and the observable updates the ngFor will re-render.

Comment: OK so does that imply then that `contacts` is an observable?  Also IIUC if we use the `async` then the contact list rerenders automatically anytime the corresponding observable is updated?

Comment: Just read the documentation again linked by @ryanlutgen and it seems that the first comment is the case.  Nice.  Seems like a really nice piece of engineering genius.

Comment: Yes and yes. The async pipe is only used on observables and the screen will automatically update

Comment: Super thanks - also found an article with some good examples so I'll just post it in case others come across the topic: https://juristr.com/blog/2017/06/new-enhanced-ngIf-and-ngFor/#enumerate-ngfor-loops-using-as-and-async-pipes